# Zip in spark.How does it work and what about its performance?

Tags: apache-spark, join, zip

I am currently using zip for joining two rdd.I want to know if it's better than join operation?I can't find anything about its performance also.

Answer (score 1):

We will need more information: (1) How big are the data sets your a joining, (2) are you noticing any performance issues from the join, (3) Between your data sets is their a large discrepancy in number of rows, and (4) is this simply a lookup-join are something more complicated? This will help us tell you if you need to modify any of your configurations when building the spark session, any techniques to limit the amount of data entering the join action, and give our opinions on next steps you are going to want to take.

At the moment I will give you my high-level two-cents. If you are doing many actions in a line or many seperate actions, you are going to want to persist your input objects. If you have a mass row discrepancy issues (1000 rows left and 100 M right) you are going to want to broadcast the join conditions on the lower-side. If you have a large data set that you are simply searching for specific hits to do appropiat actions on the inner and outer objects, you are going to want to select only the join conditions, join them together and find the 'joined' and 'unjoined', throw them into arrays and do a filter (i.e. val knownZIPDF = inputDF.filter($"ZIP".isin(arrayOfKnownZIPs)) ), where you are going to be able to get around a mass skewed join and still get the performance you are looking for. Lastly spark configurations, depending on your persistnce, size-of-files, and the metrics on your Spark box you can mess with your serialization, executor/driver memory, executor cores, and innate spark-sql-join-partitions to ***possibly*** help action run-time.